# Bounded metric notation significance?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, notation

Is there any significance of the notation for the bounded metric $$\bar{d}(x,y)=\text{min \{}d(x,y),1\text{\}}$$
having the same notation as topological closure? Is this a nod to the word "bounded" or indicative of something more consequential? Otherwise, is there any specific reason for this notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we could have used any notation, like $d'$ or $d_t$ or whatever you like. As long as it's defined *somewhere*. It's by no means a "standard" notation.